# InterfaceError: cursor already closed

Tags: django, gunicorn, psycopg2, python-3.11, postgres-12

We have a Django 4.0.4 site running. Since upgrading from Python 3.10->3.11 and Psycopg2 from 2.8.6->2.9.3/5 and gunicorn 20.0.4->20.1.0 we've been getting random InterfaceError: cursor already closed errors on random parts of our codebase. Rarely the same line twice. Just kind of happens once every 5-10k runs. So it feels pretty rare, but does keep happening a few times every day. I've been assuming it's related to the ugprade, but it may be something else. I don't have a full grap on why the cursor would be disconnecting and where I should be looking to figure out the true issue.

Psycopg version: 2.9.5 & 2.9.3
Python version: 3.11
PostgreSQL version: 12.11
Gunicorn

The site had been running for 1-2 years without this error. Now it happens a few times every day after a recent upgrade.

Comment: Same thing happening for me too. Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same 'heisenbug' in our system and are attempting to solve it (unsuccessfully so far) ...